# VLC is set to open the folders (Home, desktop, documents etc) in the Places menu. How to reset this?

Tags: nautilus, file-association

So I downloaded something with Kget and somehow set all the folders in the Places menu to open in VLC rather than in the default file manager. How do I clear this?

Answer (score 14):

You are probably seeing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/603833). You need to open Nautilus, right click on a folder, and go to the Open With Other Application... in the right click menu and set it back to File Browser

[image]

Don't forget to make sure the checkbox for "Remember this application for folder files" is checked!

Comment: Same goes when it happens in Kubuntu. Select a folder with Dolphin and make sure it opens doing what Jorge says with Dolphin. This also applies if you install for example the Kubuntu Desktop in Ubuntu. Sometimes your system will start opening folders in Ubuntu with Dolphin. To fix this follow what Jorge mentions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it wouldn't work this way, simply because there is no checkbox for "Remember this application"!

So I had to find a way out:

- 1) I launched Dolphin (instead of nautilus)
- 2) Selected (any) a folder, and called popup menu (right-clicked on a folder).
- 3) Clicked on the "Properties" in the popup menu.
- 4) On the "General" tab there is a wrench (see screenshot 2).

screenshot 2 - "The wrench"

- 5) You'll be able to see the list of the preferred applications:

Screenshot 3 - "Preferred applications list"

- 6) Remove VLC from the list, and set nautilus first.

PS. I do have Dolphin installed, but there should be a way with other apps as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to reset VLC settings, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on your keyboard and execute the `vlc --reset-config` command.

Comment: Nope, it's not vlc. It's something to do with the default program used in gnome (I guess?) to run links in the Places menu