# Opening a Nautilus bookmark launches VLC / browser

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VLC is set to open the folders (Home, desktop, documents etc) in the Places menu. How to reset this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13958/vlc-is-set-to-open-the-folders-home-desktop-documents-etc-in-the-places-menu)

I came back after a month long vacation to check out my parents computer, only to realize that the bookmarks (e.g. Places → Downloads) opened up VLC. To try and fix this, I uninstalled VLC. But when I open those bookmarks, the browser (Firefox) launches instead.

How do I fix this and get Nautilus to launch?

PS. I'm using docky, and opening mounts from docky also has the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you have most likely done the same for a folder with VLC in the past with this tick engaged (annoyingly it is ticked on by default) which causes the problem initially.
Just right click on any folder and select the option "open with".
From the list choose "Fie Browser" and ensure the tickbox for "Remember this application for "folder" files" is TICKED.

That's all. If you want more discription with example snapshots visit here, http://thasulinux.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/folders-opens-with-vlc-in-ubuntu/

:)

Comment: I can't see folders. The file manager has disappeared from the launcher. WTF. Anyway to launch from terminal?