# Wrong app starts (VLC) instead of Nautilus while opening a directory (Ubuntu One personal Cloud, Documents)

Tags: nautilus, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VLC is set to open the folders (Home, desktop, documents etc) in the Places menu. How to reset this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13958/vlc-is-set-to-open-the-folders-home-desktop-documents-etc-in-the-places-menu)
>   [Opening a Nautilus bookmark launches VLC / browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23475/opening-a-nautilus-bookmark-launches-vlc-browser)

I start Ubuntu One to check my documents in my personal cloud.
Then I follow tab "cloud" and link "Documents".
This results in starting VLC and showing the directory content as if it were a play-list.
I would expect Nautulis to start (To be able to browse through my files).

Somehow it seems to be a wrong or corrupted file association, but where to check of change this?

p.s. I'am a non-computer literate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a Nautilus bookmark launches VLC / browser](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23475/opening-a-nautilus-bookmark-launches-vlc-browser) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/13958/vlc-is-set-to-open-the-folders-home-desktop-documents-etc-in-the-places-menu

Comment: Since you are new ;-) Check the links I posted: you have or somehing probably set 'open with' to VLC for 'folders'.