# Need help with exploring a USB drive

Tags: unity, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VLC is set to open the folders (Home, desktop, documents etc) in the Places menu. How to reset this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13958/vlc-is-set-to-open-the-folders-home-desktop-documents-etc-in-the-places-menu)

When I plug in a USB drive, I see it on the left hand edge of the Unity desktop (11.10, 64 bit) but when I try to explore it, VLC starts and tries to play whatever it can find in the USB drive.  This behavior began when I updated from 11.04 to 11.10.  I literally cannot look into the contents of any of the USB drives I have, because I cannot stop VLC, nor can I do anything when I click Open other than watch VLC start up.  This is very frustrating because it makes my USB sticks essentially useless.

HELP!

I'm sure that there is something a wizard could do about this, but I am not a wizard, and I am at my wits ends.  Trying to get to the System Settings menu works, and I can see the setup for "Removable" devices, and they are all set to "Ask" but that is clearly not what is happening.  So it looks like I must reach for the command line, but where do I go to find the settings for what the desktop does when I plug in a USB drive and wish to explore the file structure in it and possible copy a file into the USB or from the USB drive.  Right now, VLC media player is always getting in my way.  :-(

Comment: This looks like it's this problem, let me know if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13958/vlc-is-set-to-open-the-folders-home-desktop-documents-etc-in-the-places-menu

Comment: Alternatively, you can press Alt+F2, run `exo-preferred-applications`, click the `Utilities` tab, select `Nautilus` in the `File Browser` drop-down menu, and click `Close`. (If this question doesn't get closed as a duplicate, then perhaps someone can make an answer that includes the information in, and expands on, both these comments.)

Answer (score 0):

This may sound dumb but have you tried right-clicking on the icon? Otherwise try open homefolder and click on the mounted icon to the left.

[image: like on this picture]

Hope it helps!