# Unity links to USB drives do not open nautilus

Tags: unity, nautilus, usb, default, default-programs

Whenever I press my usb drives in the unity launcher, I get the folder opened with gitk instead of with nautilus. The same happens when I connect them to the computer. How do I fix this? This is happening in 11.10.

Comment: You should edit in what release of ubuntu you're using. This was an issue for a while, shouldn't be anymore

Comment: I just did that.

Comment: Can you try this? http://askubuntu.com/a/14005/235

Comment: I had already done that. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

If there are any lines that start like this `inode/directory=`then delete it/them

Save & try again. The most likely would be to see `inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`, in any event remove any inode/dirctory= line(s)

The other fairly likely solution would be to do a update, you 'd probably solve with that

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/876788