# Ubuntu seems to mount flash drives and SD Cards, but they will not open in Nautilus

Tags: 14.04, mount, nautilus, default-programs, shotwell

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit, and have had essentially no issues with it thus far. However, whenever I plug in a USB flash drive or an SD card, it seems to open in Shotwell. First I went to the "System Settings" and then "Details" and tried to adjust the default actions upon removable media being inserted, as I was almost certain that those settings would be pertinent to the issue. No settings changed the issue, at all.  If I right click on the Unity icon, and then click "Open" or even left click the Unity icon, it first opened in Shotwell, never Nautilus. Does anybody know what I could do to simply open removable media in nautilus once again, or at least have the option in Unity? The drives appear to be fully mounted at all times. I am able to access the drives by opening Nautilus, plugging in the removable media, and waiting for the removable media to appear in the left column, that works perfectly fine. The remaining issue is the automatic opening of Shotwell upon inserting removable media, and the lack of ability to open the device in Nautilus automatically or from Unity. All help appreciated!

Comment: I am unable to duplicate your results. perhaps someone else can chime in.

Comment: Do you need/want shotwell?

Comment: Thank you very much Richard. In desperation, I reinstalled completely my Ubuntu, which took time but brought also some advantages (good cleaning - I kept updating Ubuntu since about 3 years). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just fixed it. Here was my solution.

First, I edited the mimelist

```
sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

and searched for any entries that started with `inode/directory=` and deleted them as pursuant to [doug's solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100925/unity-links-to-usb-drives-do-not-open-nautilus?rq=1) regarding "Unity links to USB drives do not open nautilus." Coincidentally, the entry linked to shotwell and looked something like

> inode/directory=...shotwell;

Then, I installed Ubuntu Tweak via:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

and opened Ubuntu Tweak.

Under the File Type Manager (a mime list module) I went to 'All' and looked for the file type 'Folder'. This file type was linked to Disk Usage Analyzer, so I changed that back to Nautilus and everything worked normally.

No more opening in a random application by default, and no more failing to open in nautilus when clicked from Unity. Let me know if this solution works for anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Try System Settings - Details - Removable Media and change all options to Ask what to do. Try having nautilus open when you insert the flash drive or SD card. It should appear in the left hand column as a removable ejectable drive and you can browse it normally.

Comment: I changed every option to "Ask what to do" but it still insists upon opening in Shotwell (which I re-installed since my last post). The tip regarding already having nautilus open, and browsing it in the left hand column worked; I was able to access the removable devices. However, the primary issue of every removable device opening in Shotwell still remains. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @RichardCheek the question I was answering is the one above. you may wish to edit to include the new information. 
Thank you!